# If $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$, are $e^{\lambda_i}$ eigenvalues of $e^A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...\lambda_n$. Then, are $e^{\lambda_1},...e^{\lambda_n}$ eigenvalues of $e^A$? Here, $$e^A = I + A + \dfrac{A^2}{2!}+...\dfrac{A^k}{k!}+...$$

Comment: Yes they will be. Are you looking for a proof?

Comment: Yes, I am, thank you. Could you provide me a reference, or a hint at the proof?

Comment: I don´t kow how you would proof that for not diagonalizable matrices. But if A is diagonalizable you get
$g^{-1}Ag=D$ and then $exp(g^{-1}Ag)=exp(D)=g^{-1}exp(A)g$

Comment: First show (for example by induction) that $\lambda_i^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$ for  every integer $n$, i.e. if $Av=\lambda_i v$ then $A^nv = \lambda_i^n v$. Now consider $e^Av$ using the series expansion.

Comment: Can we take log to the base $e$

Comment: Matrix logarithms are not always unique.

Comment: For non-diagonalizable matrices, take a limit of diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: Do you know Jordan Canonical Form?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then it can be written $A = SDS^{-1}$, then $$A^k = (SDS^{-1})^k = (SDS^{-1})^{k-2}(SDS^{-1})(SDS^{-1})$$ where we see that $DS^{-1}SD$ in the middle can be simplified to $D^2$ and then by induction we can show that $A^k = SD^kS^{-1}$ and as $D$ contains the $\lambda_i$ on the diagonal then they themselves will be powered by k. Then you see that for each eigenvalue each term will become $\frac{{\lambda_i}^k}{k!}$ and that series must be $e^{\lambda_i}$.

Comment: Thank you. This works only for diagonalizable matrices though. What if $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: You could write a non-diagonalizable matrix as a limit of diagonalizable matrices and then the result will follow.

Comment: The simpler approach is to simply note that if $Av = \lambda v$, then $e^Av = e^{\lambda} v$ (as one can determine by expanding the sum).